# SwiftUI 2.0 on Big Sur how to disable resizing of Sheet

Tags: macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I have a project on Mac OS that uses sheets quite a bit to present data however setting fixedSize on the sheet doesn't disable it from resizing.

Does anyone know how to get a sheet to not resize on Catalina and SwiftUI 2.0?

This again is for Mac OS BigSur.

```
struct SheetView:View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("hello world")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var opened: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Open sheet") {
            opened.toggle()
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $opened) {
            SheetView()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I write this, SwiftUI 2.0 is beta software and during this beta phase, `.fixedSize` is undergoing active development by Apple. I suspect that once the software is released proper, this view modifier will function as expected. In the meantime I'd recommend that you file feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but for now it can be fixed by:
`.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)`

Answer (score 0):

Provide explicit frame for sheet view, like below

```
  .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheetView) {
        SheetView()
            .frame(width: 400, height: 300)     // << this !!
    }
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. It allows you to resize the sheet.

Comment: It works here. Tested with Xcode 12b5. Would you provide your code to reproduce?

Comment: I have added some code to the original post.. Even if you set the view it still allows it to be resized.